# Create an object name from a String

Tags: java, swing, events, actionlistener, jmenuitem

I asked this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12223196/230513) a few hours ago, but I think I didn't explain myself well.
Here is my code:

```
for (a = 1; a < 14; a++) {
    JMenuItem "jmenu"+a = new JMenuItem(String.valueOf(a));
    "jmenu"+a.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            rrr[a] = a;
            texto.setFont(texto.getFont().deriveFont((float) a));
            current = a;
        }
    });
    tamano.add("jmenu"+a);
}
```

What I need to do is create several `JMenuItem`s with these names:

```
jmenu1
jmenu2
jmenu3
jmenu4
etc...
```

---EDIT----

What I want is that each `JMenuitem` has a different name:

```
JMenuItem "jmenu"+a  //with this I can't create the JMenuItem; it's not permitted
  = new JMenuItem(); //I dont care about this
```

Comment: What is your intent? Why do you want to name your variables that?

Answer (score 9):

You can't name variables programmatically.  If you want 14 different components, then create an array or a List to hold those components, then create those components in a loop and add them to your array/list.  If you want the nth component, you can use components[n] or list.get(n) to get it.

Comment: The list sould be like This? JMenuItem[] menues= new JMenuItem[14]?

Comment: @BladimirRuiz Yes something like that.  To be precise, that's an array (not a list).

Answer (score 4):

There are 2 issues here

The first is building up the `JMenuItem` array

```
JMenuItem[] menuItems = new  JMenuItem[14];  
for (int a = 1; a < 14; a++) {
    menuItems[a] = new JMenuItem(String.valueOf(a));
    menuItems[a].addActionListener(new MenuItemAction(a));
    tamano.add(menuItems[a]);
}
```

The second is using the values in the `ActionListener`. Because each menu has its own associated value, a concrete class is better than an anonymous one here:

```
class MenuItemAction extends AbstractAction {
    private final int associatedValue;

    public MenuItemAction(int associatedValue) {
       this.associatedValue = associatedValue;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       JMenuItem menuUtem = (JMenuItem)e.getSource();
       System.out.println(associatedValue);
       // do more stuff with associatedValue
   }
}
```